# Masking Layer using Keras Functional API

Tags: time-series, theano

I'm trying to use Keras' Functional API as I need to add additional input into my recurrent neural net between two layers.  This would be fine however I also have input I want to forecast and so I'm using a masking layer to keep the out of sample data from affecting the model.  The masking layer throws an error when I try to pass it an Input(...) as it's expecting a list of integers not tensor variables.  Is there a specific masking layer for the Functional API?  Here is my code:

```
import numpy
import pandas
import math
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import GRU
from keras.layers import SimpleRNN
from keras.layers.core import Masking 
from keras.optimizers import Adam
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.optimizers import Nadam
from keras.layers import TimeDistributed
from keras import initializations
from keras.layers import Input, merge
from keras.models import Model


dataframe = pandas.read_csv('C:/Users/RNCZF01/Documents/Cameron-Fen/Economic Ideas/LSTM/LSTM-data/GDP+stockmarket.csv',  usecols=[1,3], header=None, engine='python')
dataset = dataframe.values
dataset = dataset.astype('float32')

dataframe1 = pandas.read_csv('C:/Users/RNCZF01/Documents/Cameron-Fen/Economic Ideas/LSTM/LSTM-data/GDP+stockmarket.csv', usecols=[0], header=None, engine='python')
dataset1 = dataframe1.values
dataset1 = dataset1.astype('float32')

train, test = dataset[start:train_size+test_size,:]*mult, dataset1[start:train_size+test_size,:]*mult
#set the masking to 0.0
for each in range(test_size):
    train[train_size + each,:] = [0.0,0.0]
train, test = train[:259], test[:259]
validx, validy = dataset[start:train_size+test_size,:]*mult, dataset1[start:train_size+test_size,:]

main_input = Input(shape=(259,2), name='main_input')
m = Masking(mask_value=0.0)(main_input)#error is her because masking expects indices to be integers not a tensor variable
```

Here is the [data](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B2Kz5NTvWjJuSzcxc0dmX3lVMEE).  Use columns 0 as the test data and columns 1 and 3 as training data in the code.

Comment: I do not understand your comment about the error occurring. Which error exactly? Also, this is not reproducible as anyone trying to help has no access to your local files. Can you provide some sample data?

Comment: I confess I am not really sure which error anymore as I've moved on without figuring this out but I did add data and help would still be appreciated

Comment: This is still very vague and it is not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you provide more context? With guessed values for `start`, `train_size` and `mult` the code you provided so far just works but does nothing really. Taking the guessing even further I'd say that you may be missing that keras models by default work on batches of data.

Comment: start is = 0 train_size = 239 and mult = 1.  What do you mean by, "I'd say that you may be missing that keras models by default work on batches of data?"

Comment: Let's suppose we're compiling a model like this, calling `model.fit(train, ...)` will give an error:
`ValueError: [...] expected main_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (259, 2)`
That is, `train` right now looks like only containing *one* sample. `fit` however expects more samples.
Something like replicating `train` `x = np.zeros(100, 529, 2); x += train; model.fit(x, ...)` may work (but not really make sense).
But then still the output is missing. Should this be `test`?

Comment: Yes test is the output which is 1 sample, 259 time steps or whatever and 1 output per time step

Comment: This is poor choice in variable names then, `train` and `test` should be reserved for your actual training and testing data sets. Something like `x` and `y` is more common here. However, as I still can't figure out what your actual goal is and the original question is now known anymore, I can not help you more (and the comment section is not the right place for this chat).